# problem when adding item to hooks state react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to store a list of items in localstorage using `hooks` and `state` like . but it returns an error

```
TypeError
cartList is not iterable
```

this is my code: (and this is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-bird-fnz7dn?file=/src/App.js))

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]);
  const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let localCart = localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "{}";
    console.log("localcart", localCart);
    if (localCart) {
      localCart = JSON.parse(localCart);
    }
    setCartList(localCart);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const arr = e.target.id.split("-");
    const selectID = arr[1];
    console.log("selectID", selectID);
    setCartItem({ ...cartItem, id: selectID });
    console.log("cartItem", cartItem);

    let itemIndex = -1;
    for (const entry of Object.entries(cartList)) {
      console.log("entry", entry);
    }
    if (itemIndex < 0) {
      setCartList([...cartList, cartItem]); // error occurs here according to codesandbox
      localStorage.setItem("cartList", JSON.stringify(cartList));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Button
        variant="link"
        id="item-12"
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, cartItem)}
      >
        item no.12
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="link"
        id="item-100"
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, cartItem)}
      >
        item no.100
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You initialize `cartList` as an Array, but then set it as an Object if not found in localStorage `let localCart = localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "{}";`. Objects aren't iterable, and setting it as a string to be parsed manually is odd. You need `let localCart = localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "[]";` but I would recommend just skipping the parse if not found in localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are getting `TypeError: cartList is not iterable` is because you have initialized the `cartList` incorrectly.

Please have a try in console following snippet, You will face exactly same error.

```
console.log( [...{ prop: 'value' }] )
```

So you should initialize `cartList` as `[]` rather than `{}` inside the `useEffect` hook like the following.

```
let localCart = localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "[]";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing about a type of `cartList`. I guess it would be an `Array`.

```
const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]); // It is declared as Array
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let localCart = localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "{}"; // But initialized as Object this line
    console.log("localcart", localCart);
    if (localCart) {
      localCart = JSON.parse(localCart);
    }
    setCartList(localCart);
  }, []);
```

```
 if (itemIndex < 0) {
    setCartList([...cartList, cartItem]); // It should be an Array, but error occured as it's an Obejct.
    localStorage.setItem("cartList", JSON.stringify(cartList));
 }
```

Comment: You have pointed out the problem but not shown the solution. (get rid of the `|| '{}'` and move the `setCartList` inside the `if` block.)

Answer (score 0):

As @pilchard pointed out, you are setting cartList as an object on that line:

`localStorage.getItem("cartList") || "{}";`

So on first render before setting the carlist value to localstorage you are setting the state as an object which cannot be spread inside an array